# Compass output_style

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Has anyone found any documentation of what the different values for output_style in Compass mean? The options are :expanded, :nested, :compact and :compressed. I can see what the last one is, but what do the others do?

Seems a bit of a waste that I have to recompile all my CSS to figure out what these different options produce.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The output styles are covered in [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style).

> Although the default CSS style that Sass outputs is very nice and
>   reflects the structure of the document, tastes and needs vary and so
>   Sass supports several other styles.
>
> Sass allows you to choose between four different output styles by
>   setting the :style option or using the --style command-line flag.
>
> #### :nested
>
> Nested style is the default Sass style, because it reflects the
>   structure of the CSS styles and the HTML document they’re styling.
>   Each property has its own line, but the indentation isn’t constant.
>   Each rule is indented based on how deeply it’s nested. For example:
>
> ```
> #main {
>   color: #fff;
>   background-color: #000; }
>   #main p {
>     width: 10em; }
>
> .huge {
>   font-size: 10em;
>   font-weight: bold;
>   text-decoration: underline; }
> ```
>
> Nested style is very useful when looking at large CSS files: it allows
>   you to easily grasp the structure of the file without actually reading
>   anything.
>
> #### :expanded
>
> Expanded is a more typical human-made CSS style, with each property
>   and rule taking up one line. Properties are indented within the rules,
>   but the rules aren’t indented in any special way. For example:
>
> ```
> #main {
>   color: #fff;
>   background-color: #000;
> }
> #main p {
>   width: 10em;
> }
>
> .huge {
>   font-size: 10em;
>   font-weight: bold;
>   text-decoration: underline;
> }
> ```
>
> #### :compact
>
> Compact style takes up less space than Nested or Expanded. It also
>   draws the focus more to the selectors than to their properties. Each
>   CSS rule takes up only one line, with every property defined on that
>   line. Nested rules are placed next to each other with no newline,
>   while separate groups of rules have newlines between them. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> #main { color: #fff; background-color: #000; }
> #main p { width: 10em; }
>
> .huge { font-size: 10em; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
> ```
>
> #### :compressed
>
> Compressed style takes up the minimum amount of space possible, having
>   no whitespace except that necessary to separate selectors and a
>   newline at the end of the file. It also includes some other minor
>   compressions, such as choosing the smallest representation for colors.
>   It’s not meant to be human-readable. For example:
>
> ```
> #main{color:#fff;background-color:#000}#main p{width:10em}.huge{font-size:10em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline}
> ```

Comment: Oh there it is! Thanks a lot iolmaus.

Comment: Can I change the output format during execution? Is it possible to process a part of my SCSS code as `:expanded` and a part as `:compressed`? If so, where do I need to add the `:expanded` and `:compressed` options to make this possible?

Comment: @JohnSlegers Normally not. You might try to fiddle with it though. Are you using Compass as a command line tool or programmatically via Ruby? Would you like different output to appear in one file or separate files?

Comment: @Andrey 'lolmaus' Mikhaylov : I'm using Netbeans and Sass 3.3. I'm not using Compass. I'm looking for a way to automaticly compile the same SCSS code into two different CSS files that use respectively `--style compact` and `--style expanded` from within Netbeans. For example, I want my file `assets/scss/colors.scss` to be compiled to both `assets/css/expanded/colors.css` and `assets/css/minified/colors.min.css`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804021/sass-in-netbeans-7-4 .

Comment: You have to run the command twice, there is no other option. If you can't figure out how to do that with Netbeans, consider creating a shell script that runs Sass twice and have Netbeans run the script instead of running Sass. Also consider using Grunt or a similar task runner.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I get it now.. :expanded is the default:

:expanded

```
#date .day {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #AAA;
}
```

:nested

```
#date .day {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #AAA; }
```

:compact

```
#date .day { display: block; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 30px; color: #AAA; }
```

:compressed

```
#date .day{display:block;padding-top:5px;font-size:30px;color:#AAA}
```