# SASS In NetBeans 7.4

Tags: css, netbeans, sass

I'm in use of NetBeans 7.4 on Windows 7 (64 bit).
With this I have installed Ruby200-x64 so I can make use of Sass (.scss to .css).

The CSS Preprocessors is configured like this in NetBeans: C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\sass.bat

**Questions:**

1. How can I make Sass output compact or compressed css after compiling?

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I've found something pretty simple.

***Assuming you've installed Ruby200 and NetBeans 7.4 on your system already.***

1 - Start "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" and type `sass -h`.

Sidenote: If you don't have Sass installed do: `gem install sass` and you'll get latest version of Sass. In NetBeans setup the CSS Preprocessors by clicking on Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Sass path click on Search and you get `C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\sass.bat`

You will get a punch of options for Sass including `--style NAME`.

2 - Go to your NetBeans project, right click at the top level of it

3 - Select "Set Configuration" > Customize, then window called "Project Properties" pops up

4 - On Project Properties window select "CSS Preprocessors", then look for "Compiler Options"

5 - Use `--style compact` for compact css output. 
 Also available are `--style compressed`, `--style expanded`

**Screenshots**

[image: Sass Options]
[image: NetBeans Sass Setup]
[image: NetBeans Set Configurations]

Comment: Is there a way to automaticly compile the same SCSS code into two different CSS files that use respectively `--style compact` and `--style expanded`? For example, I want my file `assets/scss/colors.scss` to be compiled to both `assets/css/expanded/colors.css` and `assets/css/minified/colors.min.css`. I'm looking for this feature, because I'm working on a new version of Cascade Framework (http://www.cascade-framework.com/) and I want people who don't use Sass to use the expanded CSS files for development and people who do use Sass to use the SCSS files for development.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is really possible when using NetBeans.
But I could find a work around when you use Prepros with this thread:
https://github.com/sbspk/Prepros/issues/38.

Let me know if this helpful to you.

Comment: I want to have as little dependencies as possible. I'm not even using Compass. Can I change the output format during execution? Is it possible to process a part of my SCSS code as `:expanded` and a part as `:compressed`? If so, where do I need to add the `:expanded` and `:compressed` options to make this possible? That would solve my problem as well :-)

Comment: When I downloaded Ruby200 (x64), I couldn't `gem install sass`. So I installed Ruby193, then `gem install sass` worked. But I can't find any `sass.bat` in the sass folder... only `sass`, `sass-convert` and `scss` files are there. How could I find `sass.bat` ?

Comment: My bad, just found it. I was searching in the gem directory not in ruby root path